# JMeter java API - load test runs but no requests are received on the server

Tags: java, jmeter, load-testing

I've a Spring Boot server running on my localhost:8181 and I can make GET requests to it with success and I see the logs printed out.

Now I made a proof of concept for a load test. I'm using the JMeter Java API to send requests to the Spring Boot server using the Java API from JMeter. JMeter runs the test suite and no errors are reported but on my server I so no incoming requests.

Here's the load test code I'm using:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        // Engine
        StandardJMeterEngine jm = new StandardJMeterEngine();

        JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome("C:\\Users\\daz\\Desktop\\apache-jmeter-3.2");

        // jmeter.properties
        String jmeterProperties = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource("jmeter.properties").toString().replace("file:", "");
        JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties(jmeterProperties);

        HashTree hashTree = new HashTree();

        // HTTP Sampler
        HTTPSampler httpSampler = new HTTPSampler();
        httpSampler.setDomain("localhost");
        httpSampler.setPort(8181);
        httpSampler.setPath("/job/test");
        httpSampler.setMethod("GET");

        // Loop Controller
        LoopController loopController = new LoopController();
        loopController.setLoops(1);
        loopController.addTestElement(httpSampler);
        loopController.setFirst(true);
        loopController.initialize();

        // Thread Group
        SetupThreadGroup threadGroup = new SetupThreadGroup();
        threadGroup.setNumThreads(2);
        threadGroup.setRampUp(1);
        threadGroup.setSamplerController(loopController);

        // Test plan
        TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan("MY TEST SUITE");

        // Construct Test Plan from previously initialized elements
        hashTree.add("testPlan", testPlan);
        hashTree.add("loopController", loopController);
        hashTree.add("threadGroup", threadGroup);
        hashTree.add("httpSampler", httpSampler);

        jm.configure(hashTree);

        jm.run();
    }
}
```

Can someone help me spot out what is missing/wrong here as this code is not making the requests as expected?

**------------- EDIT -------------**

Using `Summariser` I get the following output:

> summary =      0 in 00:00:00 = ******/s Avg:     0 Min:
>   9223372036854775807 Max: -9223372036854775808 Err:     0 (0,00%)

Which I believe to mean that no requests where made, as I suspected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are constructing your test plan a little bit wrong, you need to use the following code:

```
hashTree.add(testPlan);
HashTree threadGroupHashTree = hashTree.add(testPlan, threadGroup);
threadGroupHashTree.add(httpSampler);
```

Apart from this everything looks more or less fine.

References:

- [JOrphan HashTree JavaDoc](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jorphan/collections/HashTree.html)
- [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui)

You can also look at [jmeter-from-code](https://bitbucket.org/blazemeter/jmeter-from-code/) demo project to see how to build an example Test Plan using [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/)